# vs2008,vs2015 cannot read files: weird behaviour

Tags: c++, visual-studio, permissions, fstream, permission-denied

I'm having a very weird behaviour in Windows 10 enviroment using both VS2008 and VS2015 when I try to read a file using `ifstream`.

I'm using the following simple code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("C:\\Users\\dd\\Desktop\\test.txt");
    if(ifs.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        while(std::getline(ifs,line))
        {
            std::cout << line << "\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << std::strerror(errno) << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously the file exists.

When I try to read the file `.txt` I get:

> Permission denied

I run Visual Studio as Administrator and I have the permission to read the file because I am able to open it using Notepad++.

If I change the file extension, for instance `.test`, I am able to read the file content correctly and everything works as expected.

I uninstalled and then reinstalled VS2008, VS2015 and all C++ Redistributable, but nothing changed. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the file open by any other process?

Comment: No, the file is not used/opened by any other process.

Comment: Have you tried disabling your antivirus software? Or locating the text file in a different folder (not in c:\Users at all)?

Comment: Not yet because I'm using my work pc and I don't have permissions to disable the antivirus. Yes, I moved the file in another location but it still does the same "joke".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your file isn't named `test.txt`. Did you check that your file is really named `test.txt` and not `test.txt.txt` (with a hidden extension)?

Try to list files in command prompt to see what the real file name is: 
cmd>

```
  cd C:\Users\dd\Desktop\
  dir | findstr test
```

Onother possibilities:

- `test.txt` could possibly use similarly looking letters from another
  language (in your code or in actual file name).
- not properly quoted slashes in your code (e.g. `C:\Users\\` instead of `C:\\Users\\dd\\`). Try to change to forward slashes.

Comment: ***Did you check that your file is really named test.txt and not test.txt.txt (with a hidden extension)?*** Agreed. Maybe it's time to turn the "hide extensions of known types" option of Explorer off.

Comment: I already have the option off. And the file name is exactly `test.txt`. The weird thing is if I change `.txt` in `.anythingelse` everything works.

Comment: @BugsFree could it be that one of the letters is in different language? Rename it to `something.else` and then back to `test.txt` and retry.

Comment: @BugsFree check if you mistyped filename in your code then?